# simple preg_replace() that I can't get working (i suck at regex)

Tags: php, mysql, regex

```
$count_sql = preg_replace("/SELECT(.+?)FROM/", "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM", $sql);
```

It's probably pretty obvious what I'm trying to do, but I am terrible with regex.

I need to replace anything between SELECT and FROM with COUNT(*).

Tried using (.+), (.+?), (.*), and (.*?).

Comment: Your regex looks fine - can you post an example of a string you are trying to match that isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks OK... does your SQL contain newlines? If so, you'll need the `s` modifier:

```
$count_sql = preg_replace("/SELECT(.+?)FROM/s", "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM", $sql);
```